# Mamp Pro 4: Apache won't start

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I used Mamp Pro 4 for a while with no problem on my Mac (Os X 10.11), then, suddenly, Apache won't start. I got an error: "Check the log" but log is empty.

I have made several test:

- reinstalled Mamp Pro 4 (4.0.6);
- rebuild permissions using utility disk and Onyx
- update Mac os X El Captain to Sierra;
- started Apache/MySql as "www" or as "user"

Note:

- 1) starting system Apache it works
- 2) using MAMP (not pro) Apache works fine.

Any other suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Updated to MAMP PRO 4.1, still not works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed!!  The issue was in SSL. For some reasons it stopped to works. No logs and no warning occurred: just an empty log. I deleted the SSL and created a new certificate. Now Apache works fine as well.

Comment: Very interestingly solved the issue. Anyone understands why this solves it?

Comment: Thanks man, you save me a whole day to search this into my Kernel installation.

Comment: Lifesaver! I had deleted my 'self signed SSL' folder in a clean up. Reinstating it fixed the issue.

Comment: I just hate that MAMP don't have any logs or anything showing anywhere that this was the issue. Just wasted hours on multiple days until seeing this. Saved the day. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to force-quit apache? I got this issue sometimes as well and using the terminal-commands `sudo killall httpd` and `sudo killall mysqld` fixed this issue.

Sometimes I have to repeat the commands a few times.

Comment: Thanks but... nothing. httpd is not running.

Answer (score 3):

Upgraded to mamp pro 4.2.1. Now apache won't start. followed directions here: https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215197286 
Nothing in activity monitor. 
Nothing in log file.

Resolved by deleting hosts in mamp pro, where the document root had been deleted.

If you are seeing a red circle-arrow next to the Hosts link in the upper left, find the hosts that are not resolving properly to a document root, then fix them or delete them. That resolved it.

Comment: This was the answer for me. I'd removed some old projects which invalidated some of the hosts in MAMP. No error marker is shown next to the problematic hosts which is incredibly unhelpful if you have a lot of them set up.

Comment: In MAMP 6, one host was red and that caused Apache to fail silently. Thanks. https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/Apache/Apache-will-not-start/